# くれます nuances with 喜ぶ

Tags: grammar

What are the different nuances between these two sentences, due to ”くれる”?

> その絵を見て彼は喜んでくれます。

> その絵を見て彼は喜んでいます。

Do both mean "By looking at this photo, He is pleased"?

Comment: Do you know how くれる works in the first place? I suggest looking that up. Barring certain special exceptions, 私・僕・俺 etc. cannot be the subject of くれる.

Comment: Yes I've learned how to use 上げる、くれる and もらう。 And you are right my example is wrong, I will edit this!

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence with いる objectively describes a state where he is pleased looking at the picture.

> その絵を見て彼は喜んでいます。

If you add to this a sense of gratitude, or pleasure, on the part of the speaker, it would become:

> その絵を見て彼は喜んでくれています。

Maybe the speaker gave him the picture as a gift or something. Note that the verb is still used with the subsidiary いる to describe his state of mind as the speaker sees it.

The first sentence with くれる and without いる is understood as saying that he always becomes pleased (to the speaker’s pleasure) when he sees the picture, which sounds a bit weird.

> その絵を見て彼は喜んでくれます。

Another interpretation of this sentence is that he is going to be pleased (to the speaker’s pleasure) when he sees the picture, but this also sounds weird unless it is coming from someone who is telling what happens next in a story to someone who doesn’t know or something, and on top, that person must be happy that he is going to be pleased.

The same weirdness remains in the sentence without くれる, although this doesn't require the speaker to be happy.

> その絵を見て彼は喜びます。

Comment: Thanks, indeed it was a mistake on my side, during my Japanese lesson it was in the past tense. So, as I understand the sentence almost means: "By him looking at the picture, I receive his pleasure." (The actor/subject of  "見る" and "喜ぶ" is "彼" and the actor/subject of ”くれる” is "私” isn't it ?)

Comment: @Poulp - No, it's not like that. It seems you need to learn how くれる works. It doesn't mean "receive."

Comment: Yes, I struggle a bit with this grammar topic. But I learned that with くれる the speaker is getting the action of the subject in favour, so in that case, I understand that the speaker got the favour of "彼” that "彼” being happy to see the picture. Sorry to insist.

Comment: @Poulp - くれる as a subsidiary verb expresses your mood as the speaker. Him being happy to see the picture is not a “favor” for you. He is just happy to see the picture, and that in turn makes you happy because you were hoping the picture would please him. That’s your mood.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, yes. Both mean 'Looking at the picture, he is pleased' (Note 絵 is a painting and never a photo)*. I guess your uncertainty has something to do with how  *being pleased* benefits the speaker.

The benefit expressed by くれる can be the speaker's happiness in a broad sense. So the fist sentence suggests that his pleasure contributes to the speaker's happiness while the second more neutrally describes his being pleased. In the first sentence, it is possibly because the speaker painted it or bought it for him.

*Aside: These days, a photo with lots of Photoshop editing is mockingly called 絵.

---

Some extra examples:

- 今日はやっと晴れてくれた Today finally, the weather is fine (which makes me happy).
- 彼は私の手作り料理を喜んで食べてくれた He willingly ate dishes I cooked (which made me happy).